# predict method in h2o - what does predict column mean in case of classificication

Tags: r, classification, h2o, predict

Here is my code (simple classification problem with h2o)

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
df_h2o <- as.h2o(Titanic)
y <- "Survived"
x <- setdiff(names(df_h2o), y)
model_test <- h2o.gbm(training_frame = df_h2o, x = x, y = y)
pred_model_test <- h2o.predict(object = model_test, newdata = df_h2o)
as.data.frame(pred_model_test)
```

Here partial output of the last line:

```
predict        No       Yes
1       No 0.6665519 0.3334481
2       No 0.7618396 0.2381604
3      Yes 0.3836010 0.6163990
4       No 0.6665519 0.3334481
5       No 0.6665519 0.3334481
6       No 0.7618396 0.2381604
7      Yes 0.3836010 0.6163990
8       No 0.6665519 0.3334481
9      Yes 0.4391064 0.5608936
10     Yes 0.5561055 0.4438945
11     Yes 0.5684065 0.4315935
```

In row 11 predict column has `Yes`, while `Yes` probability is only 0.4315935. What are the values in predict column then?

Comment: Well, I believe the yes/no are automatic classification scheme for some default threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see documentation [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#prediction-threshold)

Prediction Threshold

For classification problems, when running h2o.predict() or .predict(), the prediction threshold is selected as follows:

If you train a model with only training data, the Max F1 threshold from the train data model metrics is used.
If you train a model with train and validation data, the Max F1 threshold from the validation data model metrics is used.
If you train a model with train data and set the nfold parameter, the Max F1 threshold from the training data model metrics is used.
If you train a model with the train data and validation data and also set the nfold parameter, the Max F1 threshold from the validation data model metrics is used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Secondary question. Is it redundant to have both validation set and nfold parameter?

Comment: Great question @user1700890, from the scientific papers I have read, k fold is cross-validating right, so you don't need another data partition that is specifically validation. However this point is debatable. I have read scientific papers that suggest cross-validation produces estimates with lower error bias in comparison to just using a validation data partition. Personally, I only using kfold cross-validation, not a validation data set.

Comment: Some great reading material if you have time.(1) Koul A, Becchio C, Cavallo A. Cross-Validation Approaches for Replicability in Psychology. Front Psychol. 2018;9. doi:10.3389/fpsyg.2018.01117
(2) Jung Y, Hu J. AK-fold averaging cross-validation procedure. Journal of Nonparametric Statistics. 2015;27(2):167-179. doi:10.1080/10485252.2015.1010532
(3) Kohavi R. A Study of CrossValidation and Bootstrap for Accuracy Estimation and Model Selection. International Joint Conference on Articial Intelligence (IJCAI). 1995.